# ReactJS App doesn't update data without refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While my code works from the functionalities, I have to click "refresh" after each click to see the changes. For example when I click "Add note" I have to refresh the page in order to see it. While it compiles successfully, the console shows three errors:
[image]

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import { withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createNote, deleteNote, updateNote } from "./graphql/mutations";
import { listNotes } from "./graphql/queries";
import {
  onCreateNote,
  onDeleteNote,
  onUpdateNote
} from "./graphql/subscriptions";

const App = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [note, setNote] = useState("");
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
    const createNoteListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const oldNotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id);
          const updatedNotes = [...oldNotes, newNote];
          return updatedNotes;
        });
        setNote("");
      }
    });
    const deleteNoteListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onDeleteNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const deletedNote = noteData.value.data.onDeleteNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const updatedNotes = prevNotes.filter(
            note => note.id !== deletedNote.id
          );
          return updatedNotes;
        });
      }
    });
    const updateNoteListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onUpdateNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const updatedNote = noteData.value.data.onUpdateNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const index = prevNotes.findIndex(note => note.id === updatedNote.id);
          const updatedNotes = [
            ...prevNotes.slice(0, index),
            updatedNote,
            ...prevNotes.slice(index + 1)
          ];
          return updatedNotes;
        });
        setNote("");
        setId("");
      }
    });

    return () => {
      createNoteListener.unsubscribe();
      deleteNoteListener.unsubscribe();
      updateNoteListener.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const getNotes = async () => {
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listNotes));
    setNotes(result.data.listNotes.items);
  };

  const handleChangeNote = event => setNote(event.target.value);

  const hasExistingNote = () => {
    if (id) {
      const isNote = notes.findIndex(note => note.id === id) > -1;
      return isNote;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const handleAddNote = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Check if we have an exisiting note. If so, then update it.
    if (hasExistingNote()) {
      handleUpdateNote();
    } else {
      const input = { note };
      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNote, { input }));
    }
  };

  const handleUpdateNote = async () => {
    const input = { id, note };
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateNote, { input }));
  };

  const handleDeleteNote = async noteId => {
    const input = { id: noteId };
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteNote, { input }));
  };

  const handleSetNote = ({ note, id }) => {
    setNote(note);
    setId(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-column items-center justify-center pa3 bg-washed-red">
      <h1 className="code f2-l">Amplify Notetake</h1>
      {/* Note Form */}
      <form onSubmit={handleAddNote} className="mb3">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="pa2 f4"
          placeholder="Write your note"
          onChange={handleChangeNote}
          value={note}
        />
        <button className="pa2 f4" type="submit">
          {id ? "Update note" : "Add note"}
        </button>
      </form>

      {/* Notes list */}
      <div>
        {notes.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id} className="flex items-center">
            <li onClick={() => handleSetNote(item)} className="list pa1 f3">
              {item.note}
            </li>
            <button
              onClick={() => handleDeleteNote(item.id)}
              className="bg-transparent bn f4"
            >
              <span>&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true });
```

Comment: What is the content of the `error` objects?

Comment: I uploaded the content here: https://gist.github.com/marcmetz/f88cfd72cf6fd2b971d18f4d0e0678da

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CLI version 2.0 and above, owner is a required argument.  This is explained more in the link below:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#authorizing-subscriptions

After I added Auth in the import

```
import { API, graphqlOperation, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

captured the current user and passed it into the subscription it started working for me.

```
useEffect(() => {
getNotes();

const owner = Auth.user.getUsername();

const createNoteListener = API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(onCreateNote, { owner })
).subscribe({
  next: noteData => {
    const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote;
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      const oldNotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id);
      const updatedNotes = [...oldNotes, newNote];
      return updatedNotes;
    });
    setNote("");
  }
});
```